# Proof of complex Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

In Reed & Simon, they state the complex Hahn-Banach theorem as:

> Let $X$ be a complex vector space, $p$ a real-valued function defined on $X$ satisfying $p(\alpha x + \beta y) \leq |\alpha| p(x) + |\beta| p(y)$ for all $x,y \in X$, and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\alpha| + |\beta| = 1$. Let $\lambda$ be a complex linear functional defined on a subspace $Y$ of $X$ satisfying $|\lambda(x)| \leq p(x)$ for all $x \in Y$. Then, there exists a complex linear functional $\Lambda$, defined on $X$, satisfying $|\Lambda(x)| \leq p(x)$ for all $x \in X$ and $\Lambda(x) = \lambda(x)$ for all $x \in Y$.

In their proof, they let $\ell(x) = \Re(\lambda(x))$ and show that $\lambda(x) = \ell(x) - i\ell(ix)$. Since $\ell$ is a real linear function that is bounded above by $p$, by the real Hahn-Banach theorem it has a linear extension $L$ to all of $X$ such that $L(x) \leq p(x)$. They then show that the function $\Lambda(x) = L(x) - iL(ix)$ extends $\lambda$ and is complex linear.

I am stuck on how they show $|\Lambda(x)| \leq p(x)$. They let $\theta = \text{Arg}(\Lambda(x))$ and say that
$$|\Lambda(x)| = e^{-i\theta} \Lambda(x) = \Lambda(e^{-i\theta} x)
= L(e^{-i\theta}x) \leq p(e^{-i\theta}x) = p(x)$$
How do they conclude that
$$\Lambda(e^{-i\theta} x) = L(e^{-i\theta}x)?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p(\alpha x + \beta y) \leq |\alpha| p(x) + |\beta| p(y)$ implies for $\alpha=e^{i\theta}, \beta=0$ that $p(e^{i\theta} x) \leq  p(x)$ and applied to $e^{-i\theta}x$ instead of $x$ that $p(x) \leq p(e^{-i\theta} x)$.

Since $\theta$ arbitrary the above means $p(e^{i\theta} x) =  p(x)$ for all $\theta$

Now by definition $L=\Re \Lambda$ since $\Lambda(x)+\overline{\Lambda(x)}=2L(x)$ hence  $\Lambda(e^{-i\theta} x)=|\Lambda(x)| $ being real means $\Lambda(e^{-i\theta}x)= \Re \Lambda(e^{-i\theta} x)=L(e^{-i\theta}x) $

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: happy to be of help;